# Dynamics CRM 365 - Cannot access Xrm.Page.entity in HTML web ressource

Tags: javascript, html, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-365

I've added an html resource in my contact form which contains only an small image in order to place it just beside a contact field. When the user clicks on it, it fires up a javascript function in which I want to get the value of a specific field of the form. The field is an attribute of the contact entity.
Here is the HTML web ressource:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        body 
        {
         margin: 0;
         padding: 0;
         }
     </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function call() {
            var phoneNumber = window.parent.Xrm.Page.getAttribute("mobilephone").getValue();
        }
    </script>
<meta>
</head>
<body style="word-wrap: break-word;">
    <img onmouseover="this.style.cursor='pointer';" src="/webresources/new_/image/image.png" onclick="call()">
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried also to get data as follows:

```
window.parent.Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("telephone1").getValue()
```

But it doesn't work either: ***cannot read entity of null***

The problem is that the getAttribut returns null despite the field of the entity that I want to get. It's always ***undefined***
Someone has an idea ?

Comment: Something's not right, both code samples you provide should work just fine.  Put a debugger statement into your call function, open dev tools in your browser, and then click call.  Then, in dev tools, when you hit the debugger, inspect window.parent.location.  Is the value that it returns what you expect?  Also inspect window.parent.Xrm.Page.  It should have a getAttribute method and a data property.  This type of investigation might reveal some error.  Also, is the error you get the same in all browsers?

Answer (score 3):

[GetGlobalContext function and ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx (client-side reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328541.aspx#BKMK_GetGlobalContext)

> Use the GetGlobalContext function when programming with web resources
>   to gain access to context information. To get the GetGlobalContext
>   function in your HTML web resource, include a reference to
>   ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx.
>
> You can use the GetGlobalContext function when you include a reference
>   to the ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx page located at the root of the web
>   resources directory.

---

Couple more suggestions:

[Webpage (HTML) web resources](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/gg309536.aspx)

Try dropping `window` from `window.parent.Xrm.Page`.

> An HTML web resource added to a form can’t use global objects defined
>   by the JavaScript library loaded in the form. **An HTML web resource may
>   interact with the Xrm.Page or Xrm.Utility objects within the form by
>   using parent.Xrm.Page or parent.Xrm.Utility**, but global objects
>   defined by form scripts won’t be accessible using the parent. You
>   should load any libraries that an HTML web resource needs within the
>   HTML web resource so they’re not dependent on scripts loaded in the
>   form.

[Use IFRAME and web resource controls on a form](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/gg328034.aspx)

Try passing inputs from form script.

> For webpage (HTML) web resources, use the setSrc method to manipulate
>   the querystring parameter directly.
>
> In an HTML page, the parameters can be accessed by using the
>   window.location.search property in JavaScript.

[Sample: Pass multiple values to a web resource through the data parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/gg327945.aspx)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer but I have access to Xrm.Page and even to Xrm.Page.Context but not to the data of the displayed entity such as contact...

Comment: Argh, didn't notice that detail.

Comment: yep... Do you have an idea ?

Comment: thank you very much. I was currently trying that solution: https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/hardworkdays/archive/2015/02/28/howto-html-js-webresources . Will try your solutions just after that :)

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that your webresource is at root label... then you must add the ClientGlobalContext reference first

```
<script src="ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

After doing that you should be able to to get the attribute value with your function by just dropping the `"window"` part first

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function call() {
        var phoneNumber = parent.Xrm.Page.getAttribute("mobilephone").getValue();
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can not take the James Wood solution that is excellent try:

**1.  You must check that your item is  in an iframe**

You can get inspired by the following script:

```
Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get('id_iframe').getObject().onload= function() {
    var element = Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get('id_iframe').getObject().contentWindow.document.getElementById('id_element_inside_iframe');
    console.log(element);
};
```

Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get('id_iframe').getObject(): Returns the HTML object iFrame

**2. You could have an event called problem.**

You can get inspired by the following script:

```
<HTML>
  <BODY onload="SetupEvents()">
    <label id="myLabel" >Click me</label>
  </BODY>
  <SCRIPT>
      function DoTheThing() {  alert('thing was done');   }
      function SetupEvents() {
          addEvent( document.getElementById('myLabel'),'click', function () { DoTheThing(); });
      }

        function addEvent(element, evnt, funct){
            if (element.attachEvent)
            return element.attachEvent('on'+evnt, funct);
            else
            return element.addEventListener(evnt, funct, false);
        }
</SCRIPT>
</HTML>
```

Comment: The HTML web ressource placed on the form are not placed inside items. I've just created a Web resource and place it on the form. I've made the same thing on Microsoft Dynamics 2015 (more specifically on Unified Service Desk) and it works nice... But on Dynamics 365 not

Comment: But after inspecting the DOM, it appears that the HTML ressource is added to an iFrame. Will try you solution.

Comment: @HubertSolecki: I do not think it will make a difference whether you put your HTML web resource in an iFrame or in a web resource control. In Dynamics CRM 2016 / 365 web resources are - in most cases - loaded earlier than the form they are integrated with. Therefore, after you attach a function to the onload event of the iFrame, you need to set the source of it as well.

Comment: @Henk van Boeijen >> " Therefore, after you attach a function to the onload event of the iFrame" -> For this reason I used Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get('id_iframe').getObject().onload....

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a Turbo Forms issue since Turbo Forms loads Javascript in parallel and loads **ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx** as one of the last items. IFrames contain an **OnReadyStateCompleted** event, I would suggest that you add the following code under that event.

```
function call() {
            var phoneNumber = window.parent.Xrm.Page.getAttribute("mobilephone").getValue();
        }
```

See picture below
[image: ReadyStateComplete]