# Dynamics CRM Plugin or Extension

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I've been following some [tutorials](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg594416.aspx) to develop a plugin for Dynamics CRM but based on my requirements it seems like it's not what I'm looking for.

```
    public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        //Extract the tracing service for use in debugging sandboxed plug-ins.
        ITracingService tracingService =
            (ITracingService)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(ITracingService));
```

It seems above code provides some hooks to post events and interaction within dynamics, what area should I look under if I wanted to embed a custom HTML with content populated via XHR within the regions of Dynamics UI, let's a subsection within the lead? Also getting some contextual information Dynamics UI fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right. Plugin is for extending execution pipeline in server side transaction.

What you want is **Web resource** of HTML type, which you can [embed](https://crmbook.powerobjects.com/extending-crm/javascript/html-web-resources/) in the Lead form.

[SO thread to read](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40927602/7920473).

`GetGlobalContext` function inside HTML web resource will give you the access to context & controls of Lead record (name & email) after referencing `ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx`. No need to pass name & email manually, though you can send them using querystring to HTML on load with `setSrc`.

Comment: thanks, I'm researching more on this, can you please point in the direction where I can pass lead name and email to the web resource. Also does dynamic supports adding some metadata about this specific lead programmatically in my javascript (web resource)?